# Accurate mathematical description of angular acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

My physics textbook says that angular acceleration is the derivative of angular velocity, but I think that this isn't accurate.

For example let's imagine that a block is tied to a rope that passes through a hole in a table. Then let's make the block revolve in a circle on this table (which is frictionless). We then pull the rope which goes through the hole and we realize that the block is spiraling into the hole, and since the moment arm of the tension in the rope is zero so there's no torque and thus angular acceleration (aka the derivative of angular velocity) is zero (torque = Inertia * angular acceleration)

But we also observe that the angular velocity of the block is increasing as it spirals towards the hole in order to conserve angular momentum, so the derivative of angular velocity (aka angular acceleration) is positive, which is a contradiction!

So I think that the book "misdefined" angular acceleration, is this right or wrong? and if it's right then what is the "true" mathematical definition of angular acceleration?

Comment: The angular acceleration is going to be the rate of change of the angular velocity. In the same way linear acceleration is the rate of change of the linear velocity. These quantities must be related by a time derivative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that you can't "misdefine" something. Angular acceleration is defined to be the time derivative of angular velocity; that is it. Instead of questioning the definition then, you should be questioning your understanding of the relationship between this definition and other physically relevant definitions.

The error is in assuming that the moment of inertia is constant.

You are correct in saying that the torque supplied by the string is $0$, and you are correct in saying angular momentum is conserved.

Therefore, we have for this system
$$\tau=\dot L=\frac{\text d}{\text dt}(I\omega)=\dot I\omega+I\dot\omega=\dot I\omega+I\alpha=0$$

So we have for all points in time
$$\alpha=-\frac{\dot I}{I}\omega$$

Since the moment of inertia is decreasing, we have that the angular acceleration will increase in the direction of the angular velocity. Which makes sense with what you said, as the angular velocity will be increasing in magnitude at an increasing rate.

How to tackle this system more numerically can be found in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/534789/179151), but for a first pass, $I(t)=mr(t)^2$, so $\dot I=2mr\dot r$ which leaves us with
$$\alpha=-\frac{2\dot r}{r}\omega$$

To go further you will need to solve the differential equation with a specified $r(t)$, but your confusion has at least been addressed.