# What would be the result of a body decreasing safe speed in a banked circular arch?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

A banked circular arch of radius $r$ makes angle $\theta$ with the ground. Any moving body of mass $m$ having speed $v$ can cross the arch safely. If they fall off from the arch for increasing speed what happens when they decrease speed? Do they accelerate towards the centre for the responsible centripetal force? Gravitational acceleration acts on them.

[image: body moving in a banked curve]

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/471316/179151

Answer (score -1):

[image: in the image you'll find some math]It will still turn safely with friction not being maximum. But their is a minimum speed after which the body will start to slid down the banking.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @Jayesh soni the object was moving in a frictionless path. i didn't mention friction. it would have been great if you could kindly answer accordingly :) .

Comment: @sidratulmuntaha if path is frictionless then simply put the value of coefficient of friction zero. And get the range

Comment: yes it all comes down to √(NRsinθ/m). there's no range. so  will it accelerate towards the centre for reducing this speed? @jayesh soni

Comment: If the speed is reduced the required centripetal force is will be smaller than the component of normal force available thus car will skid inwards